# nth-position of element inside specific class defines the custom label for event

Tags: google-tag-manager

We track link clicks inside a container with the class "mainContainer", the markup looks like this:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
   <div>
      <a href="x">link nr. 1</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      <a href="x">link nr. 2</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      <a href="x">link nr. 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have set up an event, which tracks all clicks on any of these links with the css selector .mainContainer > div > a

The event has the category "referring link" and the action "referring link clicked". As label, we would like to give the actual position/number of the link. So if link nr. 3 is clicked, the label should be named as "referring link number 3".

I assume, that I could target each link with the nth-child pseudo class, so link number three would be .mainContainer > div:nth-child(3) > a and for each click write an specific label.

Unfortunately, I don't understand, how I can get tagmanager to listen to the specific link click and write out a label into the event.

Can anybody help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, here es the solution, hope it helps somebody else:

```
function() {
  var linkedArticles = document.querySelectorAll('.mainContainer > div > a');
  var clickedElement = {{Click Element}};
  var linkPosition = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(linkedArticles, clickedElement) + 1;
  return linkPosition;
}
```